# when using OmniAuth in rails application why I always met Errno::ETIMEDOUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have a rails dummy application, And I've add OmniAuth into my Gemfile.
I've add

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Twitter", "/auth/twitter" %>
```

in my application layout file.

Also I've add the omniauth.rb file in my config\initializers folder.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, 'MYKEY', 'MYSECERT'
end
```

After I restart of my rails server with `rails s` and visit http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter

I've always met `Errno::ETIMEDOUT`, saying `Operation timed out - connect(2)`

My computer can visit Twitter website meanwhile.

Can anyone help me what was going wrong here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of the network issue. After connected with VPN, everything was fine.